# Do contractors need to attach form 1099-MISC to their income tax return?

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-1099, form-1099-misc, turbotax

Is there a source stating that U.S. contractors who received 1099-MISC forms do or do not have to attach them to their federal or state return? My impression, after a bunch of searches, is that I don't have to attach 1099s, but I'm confused by TurboTax.

TurboTax asked for the name and EIN of the entity that paid me, but I don't see any trace of the entity's name or EIN in the PDF return that it produced. Why would it ask anyway, if 1099-MISC details don't have to be submitted by individuals?

TurboTax advised only to attach the W-2, but not any 1099-MISC.

Comment: I never have, since the instructions say nothing about it, and (knock on wood!) haven't had a problem in the ~25 years I've been getting them.

Answer (score 1):

If you have tax withholding reported on 1099 - then it should be attached to the return.

Otherwise, this information doesn't go anywhere on the return, but it appears in the copies you can make for yourself (with all the worksheets etc).

Comment: [Source](http://classroom.synonym.com/need-attach-1099-forms-federal-tax-return-7577.html) corroborating that: *"If you file your return electronically, you do not have to worry about mailing any of your 1099 forms. The issuer is required to send a copy to the Internal Revenue Service as well. However, if you file a paper return, you should attach a copy of any 1099 that shows federal tax withholding in Box 4. If no tax was withheld, just mail your return without it."*

Comment: @DanDascalescu when TurboTax file your return, they create a "substitute" copy of the 1099 based on the information you provided, and attach it to the return they file. You'll see it in the worksheets in your copy. That's why *you* don't need to worry about mailing any of your 1099 forms.